# Fetch Request header not sending cookies in chrome (v90.0.44), working in Firefox(v88.0) (JS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, fetch, cross-domain

Really struggling on getting a Fetch API call to send cookies along in the request headers in Chrome (also they are not being set from 'Set-Cookie' response headers from returned API responses in Chrome). Both however, work on Firefox.

Feel like I've tried a million solutions here, can someone explain what I'm guessing is the SameSite issues for Chrome?

Our base api URL is `https://stage-api-v2.cbb.play`

Aliased hosts file for localhost:

```sh
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       local.cbb.play
```

Cookie that is set that we are trying to forward along

```
import * as cookie from 'cookie';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    res.setHeader(
        'Set-Cookie',
        cookie.serialize('refresh_token', req.body.token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 60 * 60,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            path: '/',
            sameSite: 'lax',
            domain: '.cbb.play',
        })
    );
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.json({ success: true });
};
```

Front end code that calls the API:

```js
async function renewSession(payload) {
    return await fetch(process.env.BASE_URL + '/api/user/renew-session', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
}
```

Request header in Firefox:

```sh
POST /api/user/renew-session HTTP/2
Host: stage-api-v2.cbb.play
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://local.cbb.play:3000/
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://local.cbb.play:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: refresh_token=a49d51basasdfg4a569cc43b8603ac916f72c0102ace7b463d9c2; 
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
TE: Trailers
```

Request Header in Chrome (no cookie):

```sh
:authority: stage-api-v2.cbb.play
:method: POST
:path: /api/user/renew-session
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 0
content-type: application/json
origin: http://local.cbb.play:3000
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://local.cbb.play:3000
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36
```

Response Header: (Note, removed non-important properties)

```sh
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Set-Cookie, Credentials, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin:http://local.cbb.play:3000
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length,Content-Range,Set-cookie
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
```

Comment: This issue is irrelevant to the `SameSite` attribute, You local dev environment `local.cbb.play` is as `SameSite` as `stage-api-v2.cbb.play`, so whatever the `SameSite` value is, it won't affect the transportation of cookies. You may consider about `CORS` issue.

Comment: @辛忠柱 Is there anything that you can think of that would circumvent this as I would have thought Firefox would face the same issue

Comment: You may figure it out step by step. At first you may make sure whether this cookie is set properly. Open the chrome devtools, and then switch to the Application panel to check it out.